# Consumption-based cloud service

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, vmware-server, ovh

For a current project I am looking for a cloud service which calculates the costs based on the processing power my application is using.

If my application only spends 5 minutes per hour doing any processing, a cloud service like AWS EC2 would still charge me for the whole hour. My application needs to run 24/7, however, most of the time it will not do a lot of processing and I would pay for a lot of computing power I only need at certain times a day.

Is there a cloud provider offering such a service?

Comment: AWS Lambda bills at 100 millisecond intervals.

Comment: Your edit changes things substantially. "My application needs to run 24/7" means you probably need to look into stuff like autoscaling.

Comment: Lambda is your best option. A large fraction of servers are idle a lot of the time.

Comment: I'm sorry that I asked the question in a somewhat misleading way at the beginning. I actually thought about autoscaling, however, every provider I've found offering such a service restarts the server - which doesn't work in our use-case :/

Comment: You're probably going to have to go with a VMWare type implementation then.

Comment: Is Fargate an acceptable answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I misunderstood the question, I corrected the answer and this is my new answer:
Accord the solutions of other providers you could use [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run).

you only pay when your code is running, billed to the nearest 100 milliseconds, you could review it [here](https://cloud.google.com/run#pay%E2%80%90per%E2%80%90use)

Comment: That's not what the question asks.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Fargate is offering this kind of service. This is basically a container and you are billed for the actual vCPU & RAM consumption made by the app.

Your app need to run in Docker and the server never restart even during scaling. The frame is not super wide (0,125 to 10 vCPU) but I don't know the specs you are looking for.